# Excel VBA no MAC

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, mac

Boa noite!
Utilizo bastante o VBA do Excel em um computador PC.
O VBA utilizado no Excel para MAC é o mesmo?

Comment: É uma versão simplificada. Roda em ambiente sandbox e não dá suporte a macros complexas.